# display message if time difference is greater than 50 minutes - php

Tags: php, datetime, time

Basically i'm getting time difference between current time and database time.

```
  $cur_time = time();
  $db_time = $rs[$k]['update_time'];
  $diff = abs($cur_time - $db_time);

  $months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
  $days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
  $hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 
  $minutes  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 
  $seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60));
```

Then to display the time diff in minutes, hours, days etc

```
if($hours!= 0)
  {
        if($hours== 1)
        {
            $time2 = $hours.' hour, ';
        }
        else
        {
            $time2 = $hours.' hours, ';
        }

  }
  else
  {
        $time2 = '';
  }
  if($minutes!= 0)
  {
        if($minutes== 1)
        {
            $time3 = $minuts.' minute, ';
        }
        else
        {
            $time3 = $minuts.' minutes, ';
        }

  }
  else
  {
        $time3 = '';
  }
```

same for seconds, days and months .. Then to display total time difference,

```
$timediff = $time1.$time2.$time3.$time4.' ago';
```

If my minutes is greater than 50 , I need to show message else another message.

```
if($time3 > 50 || $time4 > 1 || $time3 > 1 || $time2 > 1 || $time1 > 1)
{
    $msg = 'greater';
}
else
{
    $msg = 'lesser';
}
```

Problem is - Minutes, Hours, days are stored in seperate variable. For suppose, if my time difference is 55 minutes, which is showing

```
55 minutes ago
```

my condition is going to **if condition** which is correct. And if my time difference is  1 hour 2 minutes

```
 1 hour 2 minutes ago
```

my condition is again going to **if condition** considering only 2 minutes which is lesser than 50 min, rather it should go to else loop. How to put conditions for these time differences

Comment: There is no such thing as an **if loop**.

Comment: Why don't you work with timestamps?

Comment: I'd say that an *if statement* checks whether the *if condition* holds and either executes the *if branch* or (if one exists) the *else branch*.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DateTime class from PHP:

```php
$dt = new \DateTime('@1434438947'); //unix timestamp
$diff = $dt->diff(new \DateTime(), true);

echo $diff->days * 1440 + $diff->h * 60 + $diff->i; //minutes difference absolute
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you put your condition before conversion?

```
$cur_time = time();
$db_time = $rs[$k]['update_time'];
$diff = abs($cur_time - $db_time);

if($diff > 3000) // 3600 is 1 hour and 3000 is 50 minutes
{
     $msg = 'greater';
}
else
{
     $msg = 'lesser';
}
```

Even if the time difference is `1 hour 2 minutes` , this works fine